# CALCULATE IOPS FROM MB/S

Tags: storage, cloud

I'm going to set up three storage Ceph server with cluster. Each server has 9300-8i controller with 8*2tb sata ssd disks. Overall throughout of 8 drives and per drive throughout is mentioned below.

So 4480 MB/s   /   8 SSD   = 560 MB/s per drive.

There is no hardware raid concept here and all will be taken care by Ceph.

From just one server calculation.

IOPS = (MBps Throughput/KB per IO) * 1024

Iops = 560/4 *1024  = 143,360

560 -- Per drive throughput

4 kb ----- block size

So 1,003,520   iops from all the 8 drives?

Is this correct calc?

Comment: The 4 kB size of an IO request is something you normally only find in benchmarks. It is not "the size of an IO request"  will always be 4 kB...  The 4 kB value is often used because aligning the IO request size with the native sector/block sizes used on drives results in optimal (test) performance... But as far as I know in real life the actual values of IO requests can and will vary quite a bit and thus the number of IOPS your storage servers can support will also vary.

Comment: Yes Bob.Thanks for that.Do we have any link to cross check these?

Answer (score 2):

No, sequential throughput and random small IOPS numbers are not interchangeable. There is a difference between getting large contiguous chunks of data out as fast as the SATA bus allows, and looking up small blocks of data all over the place.

125,000 4kB IOPS in a SATA drive, essentially the theoretical limit, would be extraordinary. Do any vendors claim that high in their specs?

A storage system is further limited by the slowest component. Including interconnects. Ceph is a multiple node system. If you truly wish to saturate 8x drives worth, you would want at least 2x 25 Gb Ethernet links to get the data onto the IP network.

Comment: Thanks John.We are currently testing with 3 servers.Each server will have 8 SSD disks and the storage network with 2 * 40 Gb.Any other ref article is there to know about the calculation in detail? Thanks

Comment: Good to approximate the theoretical maximum like you did, but that is useless for finding what can be achieved in practice. We can't know every detail about this storage system, so you must test. Run tests with a workload as close to the real thing as possible.